# Where can I find a downloadable database of basic physical and chemical properties?

Tags: ionic-compounds, reference-request, covalent-compounds, databases

The web has many online databases of properties of compounds locked behind search interfaces, but I can't find anything you can actually *download*.

I want a corpus of data that might allow me to, say, sort compounds by enthalpy of formation, or melting point, or other properties you'd encounter in a high school chemistry class. I don't need environmental impact properties, or toxicology data, or even molecular structure, and I don't need to know about exotic stuff hardly anyone's ever heard of. Just the basic simple things you would expect to be easily available like just about everything else on the web.

There are handbooks of general properties of compounds. Collections like these are perfect. Surely someone has put information that exists in a book into digital format.

I don't mind paying for it. But I can't even find it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC_Handbook_of_Chemistry_and_Physics ? Theres a downloadable version, you'd have to script something to mine the data from it into a spreadsheet, however

Comment: @NotEvens -- Thanks. You mean the ebook? I dunno, it probably would be compressed or otherwise DRMed. I'm pretty sure even a PDF would be cryptic, right?

Comment: The eBook was what I had in mind, its fairly easy to extract data from a PDF, especially if you're on;ly interested in certain tables

Comment: @NotEvens -- Thanks, but I'd need to be certain the ebook data is raw enough before I spend money on it.

Comment: Regarding melting points, https://datahub.io/dataset/open-melting-point-data backed by Alfa Aesar or https://figshare.com/articles/Melt-ing_Point_and_Pyrolysis_Point_Data_for_Tens_of_Thousands_of_Chemicals/2007426 may be examples; for high school, however, likely an overkill.

Comment: Search specifically for MSDS sheets, these will be the most helpul. For molecular structures, use SMILEY or ChemSpider.

Comment: The NIST database has been succesfully crawled before. It would take some scripting as well.

Comment: http://blog.sciencenet.cn/upload/blog/file/2008/12/2008121510347360620.pdf

Comment: @DrMoishePippik -- This is very helpful. Thank you.